# onConfigurationChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I am trying to `@Override onConfigurationChanged` because I want to know when the keyboard down and when it is up but nothing happened.

What can I do? This is my source:

```
 @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
      if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
```

I also added to the manifest this line

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing `newConfig.keyboardHidden==Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES` This applies for all the keyboards whether it is attached to the device or not.

Comment: it is not even reach the if else statement

Comment: Make sure it reaches the onCnfgChngd()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown take a look at this question. You can do this also with measuring the layout.

Comment: `InputMethodManager imm = ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
if(imm.isActive())` with this you can also check if the keyboard is active since, if any of the view is active for input means the keyboard is shown.

Comment: 10x bro , i will try this two options

Comment: when i try this link stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/… , i get exception ::: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: where i need to put this code ?? i want to know every time that the keyboard shown and hide ?

Comment: For the second one you put it in onConfgChngd(). For the 1st one(link) do it as it is shown.

Comment: the first one cause exception ... the second does not even get to the onConfgChngd() this was my only problem from the beginning how can i fix it ?

Comment: i just want onConfgChngd() to work it will solve all my problems :-)

Comment: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" ` try only with this, for detecting the appeariance of the keyboard. Add in onConfgChngd() `Log.i("onConfigChange()", "Success");` to check if it inside oCC() and check the logcat

Comment: public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   Log.i("onConfigChange()", "Success");
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   //Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
      if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        
      }
  }

Comment: Below super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig) add the log.i()

Comment: If that does not work, then you should find the way with the 1st one (link). Modify it by your needs.

Comment: yessssss it's work , it is so funny the problem was that the class name was very long and the eclipse get exception or just collapsed. 10x bro